# How to figure out what is causing " cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityMainBindingImpl'"

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, data-binding

I am following the Udacity android Kotlin Bootcamp and I am on the About Me app.

I have already checked the build window as referred to in another answer after rebuilding the project on both splits to see the raw compiler output but it is just saying the same thing as in the title on the import line for ActivityMainBindingImpl.

I have already tried rebuilding my project multiple times as well as invalidate cache and restarting multiple times but all of it results in no progress.

It is the exact same problem referred to in this post https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/gq6r2e/need_help_with_this_confusion_in_data_binding/

however, I already have omitted @ in my activity_main.xml and it did not resolve the problem and is still saying that it "Cannot find identifier 'MyName'" on both

```
android:text="@{MyName.name}"
android:text="@{MyName.nickname}"
```

This error is preventing me from running the app on the emulator I also have the latest version of the SDK build, commandline, platform tools and emulator. This app was working fine before this point on the Google pixel 3 emulator I was using

**This is my app Gradle build**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aboutme"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**activity_main.xml** , where I am also getting a, "cannot find identifier 'MyName'" error on both

```
android:text="@{MyName.name}"
```

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="myName"
            type="com.example.aboutme.MyName"
            />
    </data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text"
        style="@style/NameStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@{MyName.name}"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nickname_edit"
        style="@style/NameStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/what_is_your_nickname"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/done" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nickname_text"
        style="@style/NameStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@{MyName.nickname}"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/yellow_star"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bio_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
            android:text="@string/bio"
            tools:text="@string/bio" />
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

and my MainActivity.kt

```
import com.example.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding

    private val myName = MyName("Azhar Sharif")


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)

        binding.myName = myName
        binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener{
        addNickname(it)
    }
    }

    private fun addNickname(view:View){

        binding.apply {
            myName?.nickname = nicknameEdit.text.toString()
            nicknameText.text = nicknameEdit.text
            invalidateAll()
            nicknameEdit.visibility = View.GONE
            doneButton.visibility = View.GONE
            nicknameText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        //Hides keyboard
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)

    }
}
```

Comment: clean and rebuild projects

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you don't have an identifier "MyName", but one called "myName"...

Change this

```
android:text="@{MyName.name}"
android:text="@{MyName.nickname}"
```

To this

```
android:text="@{myName.name}"
android:text="@{myName.nickname}"
```